# How to update WordPress theme files with child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make changes to a WordPress theme via FTP, and it doesn't appear to update on the live website. 
In this case I made changes to a JavaScript file:

```
../wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/scripts/frontend-builder-global-functions.js
```

Currently a child version of the theme is active on the site. Is there a process I'm missing to have my live website reflect the changes? Also, in Chrome developer tools, the file I tried to update has ?ver=3.17.6 at the end of the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to copy the updated JavaScript file from the parent into the child theme's folder, next in your child theme functions.php file use the built in WordPress functions wp_deregister_script and wp_register_script. Your code should be like this:

```
function new_child_script() {
// De-register the Divi default theme script
wp_deregister_script('frontend-builder-global'); //check the name of the default script in page source

// Register the updated script from the child theme
wp_register_script('frontend-builder-global-custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/frontend-builder-global-functions.js', 
array('jquery'));

// Enqueue the script
wp_enqueue_script('frontend-builder-global-custom-script');
}

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new_child_script');
```

Comment: Hi Ovidiu, your solution worked perfectly! I really appreciate the help. I assume a similar procedure will be done in regards to CSS? Where changes are made through the child theme?

Comment: I'm now having problems making changes to the JavaScript file again after doing this. So it worked updating the original parent file. However, now I can't update it again? Why is WordPress like this..